# Как вытянуть данные из файла в переменную?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Имеется файл (makefile), который начинается со строк:

```
VERSION = 4
PATCHLEVEL = 1
SUBLEVEL = 41
EXTRAVERSION = .2
```

Они формируют версию ядра линукса. Необходимо, чтобы мой скрипт мог сформировать из этих строк версию *4.1.41.2* и инициализировал ей переменную.
Я знаю, что можно вызвать `grep -w 'VERSION' test.txt`, склеить строки посредством `cat`, но как вычленить из этих строк цифры?

Comment: Почему все отвечающие не могут на минуточку остановиться и подумать? При *make prepare* формируется файл с готовым макро для версии. Запустив на него *cpp* (не путать с *g++*) с правильнымми параметрами получите сразу готовую строку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1. вариант с gnu/make, grep, плюс немного shell-а

например, можно использовать программу *gnu/make* для того, чтобы получить нужную вам строку (`4.1.41.2`).

для этого надо подготовить (можно прямо на лету) маленький *makefile*. в него должны попасть нужные вам четыре строки и ещё одна — с правилом (*rule* в терминологии *make*), которое и выведет значения нужных переменных.

1. получение четырёх требуемых строк:

   ```
   $ grep '^\(VERSION\|PATCHLEVEL\|SUBLEVEL\|EXTRAVERSION\)\>' файл
   ```

   выведет:

   ```
   VERSION = 4
   PATCHLEVEL = 1
   SUBLEVEL = 41
   EXTRAVERSION = .2
   ```
2. правило, печатающее эти переменные:

   ```
   all:;@echo $(VERSION).$(PATCHLEVEL).$(SUBLEVEL)$(EXTRAVERSION)
   ```
3. соединяем вместе:

   ```
   $ grep '^\(VERSION\|PATCHLEVEL\|SUBLEVEL\|EXTRAVERSION\)\>' файл; echo 'all:;@echo $(VERSION).$(PATCHLEVEL).$(SUBLEVEL)$(EXTRAVERSION)'
   ```

   выведет уже полноценный *makefile*:

   ```
   VERSION = 4
   PATCHLEVEL = 1
   SUBLEVEL = 41
   EXTRAVERSION = .2
   all:;@echo $(VERSION).$(PATCHLEVEL).$(SUBLEVEL)$(EXTRAVERSION)
   ```
4. отправим его на выполнение программе *gnu/make*:

   ```
   $ { grep '^\(VERSION\|PATCHLEVEL\|SUBLEVEL\|EXTRAVERSION\)\>' файл; echo 'all:;@echo $(VERSION).$(PATCHLEVEL).$(SUBLEVEL)$(EXTRAVERSION)'; } | make -f -
   ```

   получим:

   ```
   4.1.41.2
   ```

   что и требовалось.

---

пояснения про grep и оболочку:

- `grep '^\(строка1\|строка2\)\>'` — выведет строки, которые начинаются со `строка1` или `строка2`, за которыми идёт граница слова (`\>`) — конец строки, пробел, знак препинания и т.п.
- `{ команда1; команда2; } | команда3` — выполнится `команда1`, затем `команда2`, а всё что они вывели в *stdout*, будет передано на *stdin* для `команды3`

пояснения про *gnu/make*:

- `цель:;команда` — это просто альтернативная (в одну строку) запись правила:

  ```
  цель:
      команда
  ```
- `цель:;@команда`, или полностью:

  ```
  цель:
      @команда
  ```

  если команда предварена символом `@`, то сам её текст не будет выведен программой *gnu/make* при выполнении правила
- `-f -` — эта опция указывает, что *makefile* для интерпретации (точнее, его содержимое) следует взять из *stdin*.

## 2. вариант с awk

можно вот такую многоэтажную конструкцию использовать на языке программирования, понятном интерпретатору *awk*:

```
$ awk -F '=' 'function t(s){gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",s);return s};/^VERSION/{v=t($2)};/^PATCHLEVEL/{p=t($2)};/^SUBLEVEL/{s=t($2)};/^EXTRAVERSION/{e=t($2)};END{printf "%s.%s.%s%s\n",v,p,s,e}' файл
```

или, в виде многострочника:

```
$ awk -F '=' 'function t(s){gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",s);return s};\
/^VERSION/{v=t($2)};\
/^PATCHLEVEL/{p=t($2)};\
/^SUBLEVEL/{s=t($2)};\
/^EXTRAVERSION/{e=t($2)};\
END{printf "%s.%s.%s%s\n",v,p,s,e}' файл
```

---

пояснения:

- `-F '='` — разделителем полей будет символ `=`
- `function t(s){gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"",s);return s}` — функция, принимающая строку, и возвращающая её же, но после удаления всех пробельных символов (проблел, табуляция, перевод строки)
- `/^слово/{var=t($2)}` — если строка начинается со `слово`, извлечь из неё второе поле (напоминаю: разделитель полей — `=`), пропустить его через функцию `t()` и присвоить переменной `var`
- `END{printf "%s.%s.%s%s\n",v,p,s,e}` — после завершения обработки входного файла напечатать содержимое переменных `v,p,s,e` с указанным форматированием.

Answer (score 3):

Иногда такой простой файл можно загрузить командой `source`.
Но в этом случае есть пробелы вокруг знака =, что нам очень мешает.

Убрать их можно командой `sed`:

```
#cat test.txt| sed "s/ *= */=/"
VERSION=4
PATCHLEVEL=1
SUBLEVEL=41
EXTRAVERSION=.2
```

Теперь у нас есть текст в на выходе поожий на bash. Загрузить его можно командой `eval`

```
# eval $(cat test.txt| sed "s/ *= */=/" )
# echo ${VERSION}.${PATCHLEVEL}.${SUBLEVEL}${EXTRAVERSION}
4.1.41.2
```

Команда `eval` не безопасна. Следует её использовать только на проверенных данных.

Но это самый простой способ подгрузить такой файл в bash.

Comment: `s/ *= */=/`. а модификатор `g` в данном случае не нужен.

Comment: спасибо, исправил. так действительно лучше

Answer (score 0):

Можно так.

```
cat test | awk '{print $3}'|awk 'BEGIN{ RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }{print $1"."$2"."$3""$4}'
```

Comment: а если строки не правильном порядке окажутся?

Comment: тут вы правы. вариант в eval выглядит увереннее.

Comment: Вариант с eval опасен, как и с make. Лучший вариант был бы на чистых grep,awk и sed без выполнения кода.